# Iterating through a list of Twitter users' ID instead of users' username

Tags: python, web-scraping, twitter

I'm trying to scrape several tweets per user by the users' IDs and `snscrape` between two dates.

If I use the user's username, I have no problems. The code is:

```
users_name = ['nytimes', 'washingtonpost']
for n, k in enumerate(users_name):
    for i,tweet in enumerate(sntwitter.TwitterSearchScraper('from:{} since: 2021-01-01 until:2022-01-01'.format(users_name[n])).get_items()):
     if i>100:
        break
     tweets_list1.append([tweet.date, tweet.user.username, tweet.user.id, tweet.rawContent])
```

Then, if I use the user's ID without dates limitations, I get no errors too:

```
users_id = [90402416, 571111858]
for k, userId in enumerate(users_id):
    for i, tweet in enumerate(snscrape.modules.twitter.TwitterUserScraper(userId).get_items()):
     if i>100:
       break
     tweets_list1.append([tweet.date, tweet.user.username, tweet.user.id, tweet.rawContent])
```

But if I try to scrape tweets by using users' IDs between two dates, I do get errors:

Code 1:

```
users_id = [90402416, 571111858]
for k, userId in enumerate(users_id):
    for i, tweet in enumerate(snscrape.modules.twitter.TwitterUserScraper('since: 2021-01-01 until:2022-01-01', userId).get_items()):
     if i>100:
       break
     tweets_list1.append([tweet.date, tweet.user.username, tweet.user.id, tweet.rawContent])
```

Error:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Code 2:

```
users_id = [90402416, 571111858]
for k, userId in enumerate(users_id):
    for i, tweet in enumerate(snscrape.modules.twitter.TwitterUserScraper('from:{} since: 2021-01-01 until:2022-01-01'.format(users_id[n])).get_items()):
     if i>100:
       break
     tweets_list1.append([tweet.date, tweet.user.username, tweet.user.id, tweet.rawContent])
```

Error:

```
ValueError: Invalid username
```

Code 3:

```
users_id = [90402416, 571111858]
for k, userId in enumerate(users_id):
    for i, tweet in enumerate(snscrape.modules.twitter.TwitterSearchScraper('from:{} since:2020-03-15'.format(users_id[n])).get_items()):
     if i>100:
       break
     tweets_list1.append([tweet.date, tweet.user.username, tweet.user.id, tweet.rawContent])
```

In this last case, I'm not getting any errors but results either. `TwitterSearchScraper()` is recognizing ID's as usernames, so the results are blank.

Any idea about how to overcome any of these errors?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `snscrape` does not support searching tweets by `user id`. You have to use direct tweet API in [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/users/lookup/api-reference/get-users-id)

Comment: Please use some non personal twitter usernames (and corresponding IDs ?) for your code snippets.